# SBT package sources and binaries in a single jar

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have found this nowhere on SO or in the documentation, but I would like to create a single jar containing both the binaries and the source code. My project is a mix of Scala and Java, if it adds anything to the question.

I've found this [Github project](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) which seems interesting and might enable me to do this, but I could not manage to set it up despite of the instructions. I think it is anyway a bit overkill for my use case. Any idea ?

Comment: There is no other reasonable option but sbt-assembly. Try harder to make it work :)

Comment: There is also http://www.capsule.io/ which looks like it might be what you're after

Comment: I've managed to make use of sbt-assembly although I still need to customize it since by default it does more than what I need.Thanks @melps, I'll look into that